# Adding a general title to autoplot.lm

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, ggfortify

I'm plotting diagnostics plots for a regression model using autoplot. I would like to add a general single title for the graph.

As example:

```
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris), label.size = 3)
```

[image]
I would like to place a "Title" at the top without modifying any subplot. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I already tried grid.arrange() getting this error: Error in $<-(*tmp*, wrapvp, value = vp) : no method for assigning subsets of this S4 class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly reference the list of ggplot objects within the `ggmultiplot` object returned by `ggfortify`'s `autoplot.lm`:

```
p <- autoplot(lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris), label.size = 3)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = p@plots, top = "some title")
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

How about using `gridExtra` & `grid` packages?

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
title1=textGrob("Title", gp=gpar(fontface="bold"))
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, 
             top=title1)
```

I would write codes like this.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I'm sorry for not mentioning but I already tried grid.arrange() getting this error: Error in $<-(*tmp*, wrapvp, value = vp) : no method for assigning subsets of this S4 class.